# Retrieve meta-data of Object/Record present inside package - Oracle Dataabse

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have to retrieve meta-data of RECORD residing inside a package. 
If Object is created outside package I am able to retrieve its meta-data from **"DBA_TYPE_ATTRS"** table.However, it is not working if RECORD/OBJECT is inside package.

```
create or replace Package sp_fun_package 
is 
 TYPE pkg_table_row IS RECORD ( 
  name varchar2(100),
  age NUMBER,
  place varchar2(100)   
 );
TYPE pkg_table_type is table of pkg_table_row;
end sp_fun_package;
```

How to get MetaData info of **pkg_table_row**?

Please help , if we have some dictionary or table managed by Oracle from where metadata can be retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to retrieve meta-data of RECORD residing inside a package

A **RECORD** type is not stored in the database as an object, and hence you cannot retrieve the metadata via a view. If you are passing it as an argument, then you could query the ***_ARGUMENTS** view.

Else, the only way that comes to my mind is to parse the Package text from *_source view.

For example,

```
SELECT   text 
FROM     user_source 
WHERE    name = '<name'> 
AND      type = <program_type> 
ORDER BY line;
```

It is going to be ugly though.

Comment: Even for retrieving table pkg_table_type made up of which kind of object, I parsed Package text. But for getting Meta-data i was having some trouble. 
can You tell me something what do you mean by: " If you are passing it as an argument, then you could query the *_ARGUMENTS view."

Comment: I mean, if you are passing the record type as parameter, then you could see the details in the dba_arguments view.